# @Override кнопку back что бы действовала как кнопка Home

Tags: java, android

У меня есть класс в котором нужно обработать кнопку Back
сам класс:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment
```

Необходимо присвоить логику работы кнопке back такую же как у кнопки home.

В классе прописываю:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}


 @Override ошибка -method does not override from its superclass
```

@Override согласно документации возможно только в fragmentactivity ,но мне нужно именно в этом классе PageFragment

Comment: Я бы нехорошо подумал о программе, которая не дает привычную навигацию или себя закрыть. В общем то вы не в праве переопределять функциональность системных кнопок. Если пользователю надо свернуть - он нажмет Home. Когда он нажимает Back - он хочет на шаг назад или закрыть.

Comment: @ pavlofff
к примеру музык. плеер работает и после того как нажимаешь кнопку закрыть
у меня такая же ситуация
убить приложение,можно при длительном тапе из истории запуска..ничего нового

Comment: Это потому, что музыкальный плеер работает в сервисе и не зависит от состояния активити, которая его запустила. Рекомендую и вам искать правильное решение, а не вмешиваться в работу системных функций неочевидными изменениями.

Answer (score 2):

Все спасибо!
Ответ:

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    public void onBackPressed();
}

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        OnBackPressedListener backPressedListener = null;
        for (Fragment fragment: fm.getFragments()) {
            if (fragment instanceof  OnBackPressedListener) {
                backPressedListener = (OnBackPressedListener) fragment;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (backPressedListener != null) {
             backPressedListener.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressedListener {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // полезный код
    }
}
```